# Cant access Youtube data api v3

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-data-api

I am trying to access data api in order to search for videos based on keyword,,

```
    SearchListResponse list=search.execute();
```

But i am getting this exception:

```
    403 Forbidden
{
"code": 403,
"errors": [
{
"domain": "usageLimits",
"message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.",
"reason": "accessNotConfigured"
}
],
"message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
}
```

but i have activated the yputube data api in api console, as well as i have generated an api key which i am using in

```
    search.setKey("MY_KEY");
```

Note: i have enabled youtube data api in console for my project, and m using public api key to access this

Comment: have you configured the api for android and have you put your keystore SHA1 certificate fingerprint and package name (separated by a semicolon) and also check is your youtube channel working properly in browser( i had channel issues few weeks back and got the same error )

Comment: yes i did so,, i have solved the problem. i had to use browser api key for execute() method. As this method is part of java client api and not android client api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use "browser api key" because execute() method is part of java client api and not android client api