# How to make youtube data api v3 android key work

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I set up the Android key followed by [the steps here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application#installed-applications), but like other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363460/cant-access-youtube-data-api-v3) the Android key doesn't work, only the browser key works. I wonder if this is Google's bug or the way I use the key is wrong?

Hope Google's engineers answer this question and provide an example to show how to use the Android key for Youtube data api v3.

Comment: Can you please share your codes?

Comment: hi @Teyam
sorry for late reply, I set my email wrong so I didn't get notification about new comment.

Comment: @Teyam, [here is the code](https://www.codepile.net/pile/p0KYXKkO)

Comment: and I got the error messge:

Comment: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden

 {

   "code" : 403,

   "errors" : [ {

     "domain" : "usageLimits",

     "message" : "The Android package name and signing-certificate fingerprint, null and null, do not match the app restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions.",

     "reason" : "ipRefererBlocked",

     "extendedHelp" : "..."

   } ],

   "message" : "..."

 }